# Why cannot login to restored SQL Server 2012 database?

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

As part of the effort for developing a Windows Service, I restored a production database to a test database on the same SQL Server instance, and can access the test database just fine via SSMS. I gave db_owner role to the database to two other users that are unable to login, both getting SQL error

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
>   Login valid but database unavailable (or login not permissioned)

Here is the basic message which mentions the database in question as the problem.

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MedFile_TestDataServer'. [CLIENT: ]

The database is not in "Restoring" status.

First user is `NT Authority\System` and the second a Windows user. Both credentials are used to run the Windows service that access the database in update mode, the system user from the same server, the Windows user from VS2013 running the service as a command program on my desktop. Both can get at other copies of this same database just by changing the database name so don't think a connection string issue. I have compared every property on the databases that work and do not work and see no differences except the file names and these two logins have less permissions on the databases that they can access.

Almost like this database is being kept unavailable after being restore but I can find no such property set on the database and I can access via SSMS. I've restarted the server containing the database ergo SQL Server as well.

I also tried running the service as a database administrator and get the same error even though that user accesses the db just fine via SSMS.

Is there anything that can make the database "unavailable"?

This is part of software development for a Windows service trying to use a test database. I am using both EF 6.02 and the latest ADO.NET version as well.

Comment: Is the Windows user able to access the restored database via SSMS ?

Comment: Did you check to see if the database user is tied to the server login (i.e. orphaned users)?

Comment: @Dave - the database users do show they are mapped to the same login name.

Comment: @Sujay - yes, I can login toi the server and start SSMS and access that database just fine.

Comment: Why were two votes made to close this question? Not sophisticated enough for the question police or did I make some other faux paux? Valid questions include - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: @Dave: There's typically some pedantry around whether the question belongs here or somewhere else on the SE network (i.e. dba.stackexchange.com for this question). Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: @Dave: do you have the ability to impersonate those logins (i.e. `execute as login = 'your login here'`? If so, do that and try to use the database. Also, are there any clues in your server log?

Comment: @Ben, thx. Not sure in what context you are suggesting impersonation. My main goal is to have this new database for testing my Windows service changes but am unable to access it using 3 different users from the service, but can from SSMS. All 3 users have high privs so got to be something else I feel. I regularly restore another DB for testing using the same PowerShell script and have had no problems with those. THis is just a different database I've not restored before and need to test on. Found nothing other than what was mentioned above in the sql server or system event logs.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using `RUN AS` to run SSMS, then you are logging in with Windows Authentication? You could try Profiling the connection events in Profiler and confirm that it is the server that you expect.

Comment: @EL - I'm not using RUN AS but rather am logging on as either of two users and am able to use the database via SSMS just fine. Only when those same credentials are used by my Windows service, am I denied a login to the database. We only have one SQL server so no chance of getting that mixed up. Everything we do used Windows Authentication, no SQL users. Thx.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Our problem ended up being a strange one.  The database names had been migrated from another server.  The database names somehow ended up with spaces at the end of them!  The connection string obviously wasn't expecting this.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your database has "Auto Close" property set to "True".  If so, change it to "False".

You can see it from SSMS: right-click on database - Properties - Options.

Comment: Thx but Auto Close was set to false.

Comment: This just saved me on a SQL Express database that was refusing an AJAX connection after running complex queries to serve a page on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

can you check what is the Default database for those two users?

If you have (accidentally / purposefully) set a default database for the SQL Server Login user, and the user does not ahve permissions to access the database, you'll get this error.

Comment: Both had other db defaults, so set them to this database but no help. Here is the basic message which mentions the database in question as the problem. "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'MedFile_TestDataServer'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]"

Comment: Can you try with setting MASTER database as default for them?

Comment: The System user had Master as the default. What good would that do in any event as the error does not complain about that database?

Comment: Fwiw, all users now have master as the default db.